# What is the best and large scale solution for storing image fields in SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database

In my project i have a bit big database that has about 60 tables.
I should save and collect many image files (about 5000) which the average of their size is about 2MB in large.

the estimated size of my database would be 10 GB or even higher than!

Consider these models in code first:

```
class Document
{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get;set}
// ...
   public virtual ICollection<ImageDocument> Images {get;set;}
}
```

and

```
class ImageDocument
{
   [Key]
   public int Id {get;set}
// ...
   public Document Document {get;set;}
}
```

as you see every Document has some `ImageDocuments`.

**My Solution:**

Consider the following two-step:

1. Add `ImageDocuments` to Related Document then add the produced
   Document by calling `Add` and `SaveChange` methods from `EntityFramework`
   `DbContext`.
2. Calling a created stored procedure for every `ImageDocuments` of
       related Document. The called stored procedure use bcp command to
       extract image file from database and save it in specific path of
       server, then removes the `ImageDocument`'s data from database.

It works but i have some **problems** in this way:

1. I' can not create backup integrated file.
2. Atomicity-violation because of my save transaction gets broken to
   some small transactions.
3. Consistency-violation. maybe in calling stored procedure system
   fall in crash.
4. Durability-violation. because of deletion `ImageDocument` record to
   release database space.

**now my question is that**, are there any better solution to do this and solve the problems?

it would be great if we can create a file field in SQL server that maintain the content in files separated database file.

Comment: [SQL Server FILESTREAM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Or even better.. on disk.

Comment: I do not thing that is a good practice to save image in database. When i face same challenge, i save only the path.

Comment: @kostasch. but we dont have access to hard drive of the server.

Comment: Get an access then. It is not solution that make a db many gb beacuase you do not have access. In a previous company i was working they were doing such things. And results were very bad.

Comment: @kostasch. ok man. but i am thinking about the security, large scalability.How does it support them?

Comment: As for security you can encrypt files. Generaly that's my opinion which maybe wrong.

Comment: @kostasch. the problem is that the sharing physical location of server is not secure.

Comment: Not secure??? Why? You can do many things in order to secure it.

Comment: @kostasch. maybe, but it makes a new challenge which is overcoming the security problems. ok man. thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, you should be using FileStreams. Straight to disk, via SQL proxy.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx